# Rivering a full house

Tags: nl100

Context: Cash game (0.50$ / 1$), live. 6-max, but one player was sitting out at the time.

SB: 90$ (fairly straightforward player)
BB: 250$ (loose canon, bluffs too much)
UTG: 100$ (loose canon, currently on his third buy-in)
UTG+1: 125$ (tight, passive)
Button (Hero): 275$ (6:clubs: 6:diamonds:)

UTG limps, UTG+1 folds, I raise to 4$. SB and BB both call. UTG completes. 4 players in the hand, 16$ in the pot.

Flop: K:clubs: 8:hearts: K:hearts:

SB, BB and UTG all check. I check behind, don't want to get check-raised here by a possible king and if any of the loose players has a flush draw, they won't fold.

Turn: 5:hearts:

Flush comes in. SB, BB and UTG all check again. Don't think anyone has a K at that point, flush is more likely. I check behind.

River: 6:hearts:

Four to a flush. SB checks. BB bets the pot 16$. Total 32$ now. UTG folds, SB does not seem interested in the hand (all streets, was playing with his iPad).

Curious to see what you would have done on the river or other streets. Thx.

SPOILER. How did the hand end?

> I re-raised him, after which he went into the tank for a couple of minutes. He finally called and turned over 88 for a better full house.

Answer (score 3):

I would put in a re-raise of at least $50. Try and get some value out of the hand.

If it all folds, you've made some money still.

On the other hand if the BB decides to go back over the top of you then you are laughing :)

Answer (score 1):

Too much inactivity on the flop and the turn, which means it's likely that everyone has a marginal hand at best. I would put a $8 - $10 bet on the turn to test the waters. If someone calls and we go to the river, then you can easily bet it and extract more value from your full house (pot is bigger, which means your bet can be bigger). Instead, if you get raised on the turn, then... I don't know, it depends.

Comment: Yes, the inactivity on the flop and turn led to me believe nobody was sandbagging with a K. Could have taken a stab at it then.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify our stack size, and that's important. I'll assume we cover everyone.

I like your play on all streets.

On the river, we need to choose between calling and raising. If BB was tight, I'd be fine with just calling, but your description seems to indicate that BB is loose and perhaps stationy, so I like raising. The problem with raising is that BB is deep (and I assume we are as well), so we have a really hard decision if he 3-bets the river: either we decide to call his raise, which means that by raising we're risking a lot to win a little. Or we decide to fold to his raise, which means we might be folding the best hand if he decides to overplay a hand like KQ. This is pretty read-dependent. If you think he will never be overplaying a hand like KQ, we can also assume he will rarely be bluff 3-betting the river, so we should be raising to around 45$, and expecting him to call with basically any trips, and we fold to a raise.

Answer (score 0):

first all I'd say that I'm not a regular cash game player but I'd have raised 5 or 6$ pre. I agree with the defensive checks on flop and turn.

I'd say that BB is probably playing an Ace rag in this spot. He probably has one heart so you should extract money from him. So, without the history between you and them, I suppose I'd raise to 60-70$.

My two cents ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Great place for a minraise for value. It's thin, but you could get called by a king if you minraise.

Comment: I raised slightly more than a min-raise. Instead of 32$ I made it 40$. Figured a lot of the time he's going to make a crying call there.